# И снова частица НЕ

Tags: орфография

Предложение такое: "...иначе это будет не()удобочитаемо". Ворд мне подчеркивает оба варианты: и слитное написание "не" и раздельное. Я понимаю, что в зависимости от контекста, это слово может писать и слитно, и раздельно, но как быть в данном конкретном случае? Я написала раздельно, но потом засомневалась.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

> Я понимаю, что в зависимости от
> контекста, это слово может писать и
> слитно, и раздельно, но как быть в
> данном конкретном случае?

Да, зависит от контекста (нужен более широкий, чем у Вас приведён). Скорее всего, потребуется слитное написание.

Попробуйте воспользоваться этим правилом:

> **§ 148.** С существительными, прилагательными, наречиями на ***-о***
> отрицание не пишется слитно в
> следующих случаях. <...>
> 4. Если при прилагательном, а также при наречии на ***-о*** имеются слова
> ***очень, крайне, весьма, чрезвычайно, явно, довольно (довольно-таки),
> достаточно, вопиюще, исключительно, в
> высшей степени*** — слова со значением
> степени проявления признака,
> подчеркивающие утверждение,
>
> **§ 149..**. При отсутствии в контексте слов, помогающих распознать
> отрицание или утверждение и,
> следовательно, отличить частицу
> ***не*** от приставки ***не-***, пишущий должен проверить, какие слова
> — усиливающие отрицание или
> подчеркивающие утверждение — возможны
> по смыслу в данном контексте.
>
> **При возможности подстановки слов,
> подчеркивающих утверждение** *(очень,
> достаточно и др., см. § 148, п. 4)*,
> ***не*** **пишется слитно**.
>
> http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79

Answer (score 0):

Это прилагательное - из длинного списка тех, что "всегда" пишутся слитно:

http://books.google.ru/books?id=neBhBQAAQBAJ&hl=ru&hl=ru&pg=PA21&img=1&zoom=3&ots=BrEXlX1eOv&sig=ACfU3U0NjPDrGxWZpnjw3UrxeJUAUWWdUQ&w=685

Русский язык. Литература

Авторы: Татьяна Белецкая
Издательство: Эксмо-Пресс, 2015 г.

Comment: Александр, ваша ссылка не доступна. И почему слово ''всегда" в кавычках?

Comment: В кавычках - как цитата из заглавия списка ("Всегда пишутся слитно:"); в списке 60 прилагательных (от "невозместимого" до "неукротимого", предпоследнее "неудобочитаемый"). Почему ссылка не открывается, не знаю (возможно, cookies влияют - я извлекал в Firefox через page info). У меня открывается png - файл.

Comment: Исходная ссылка:
http://books.google.ru/books?id=neBhBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=BrEXlX1eOv&sig=ZRCCw9YHS-Zx6RO8d6aUTJJzj2w&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=MiAMVb3zFMrmyQOk44LIAg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE&f=false

Comment: По-моему, Белецкая просто пошутила! И у Букчиной с Калакуцкой ("Слитно или раздельно"), и у Лопатина в "Русском орфографическом словаре" (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%ED%E5%F3%E4%EE%E1%EE%F7%E8%F2%E0%E5%EC%FB%E9&all=x ) при слове "неудобочитаемый" проставлена звёздочка, означающая, что при определённых условиях в соответствии с действующими правилами это слово может употребляться и в слитном, и в раздельном написании.

Comment: Думаю, что при отсутствии примеров "условия" такая звёздочка выражает лишь робкое сомнение её простановщиков :) 
Пример, когда разделение возможно, я приводил (это не "удобоваримый текст", как вы его назвали, а чёрт знает что), но в нём разделение не связано с отрицанием свойства, как в рассматриваемом случае.

Comment: Alex_ander: "удобоваримый текст", как вы его назвали...===

Простите, ВЫ -- это КТО? Я прошёлся по комментариям в этой теме, ни у кого не встретил слова "удобоваримый". (Лично у меня его точно не было.)

Answer (score 0):

В примере, который вы приводите, вполне возможно, нужно слитное написание. Во-первых, можно заменить синонимом ''малопонятный''. По смыслу можно поставить такие зависимые слова, как явно,очень. и т.д. Однако поскольку нет контекста, однозначно дать ответ сложно. И еще: если автором текста являетесь вы, то и решать вам,как писать: слитно или раздельно. В зависимости от того смысла, который вы вкладываете.

При раздельном написании отрицается положительный признак, при слитном - отрицательный признак утверждается.

Comment: Я думаю, что вряд ли стилистически возможен случай "отрицания свойства удобочитаемости", поскольку слово "удобочитаемый" вряд ли является самостоятельным понятием, скорее, оно является отрицанием "неудобочитаемости", явно упомянутой или подразумеваемой. По этому в раздельном написании будет гротеск двойного смыслового отрицания - возможно, для какого-то литературного вызова это и сгодилось бы.

Comment: Другое дело, если отрицание направить не на само свойство "удобочитаемости" ("оно не такое"), а на составной объект (существительное с этим прилагательным: "это не оно"): "это не удобочитаемый текст, а чёрт знает что!". Но это за пределами вопроса.

Comment: Александр, обычно слитно пишутся те слова, которые без **не** не употребляются. А у нас есть понятие ''удобочитаемый''. Возникает вопрос: почему автор утверждает, что это слово пишется всегда слитно?

Comment: Это правило в числе прочих есть страницей раньше:
http://books.google.ru/books?id=neBhBQAAQBAJ&hl=ru&hl=ru&pg=PA20&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U3UF9HBvvq5_iCqCM5yuZdaHiSxww&w=685

А дальше - тот самый список исключений ("всегда").

Comment: Александр, ваша ссылка опять не открывается. Если можно, сформулируйте, пожалуйста, правило здесь. Очень интересно, из какого критерия автор исходит.

Comment: Там в виде скана, поэтому кратко изложу (опуская примеры). 
Не с прилагательными пишется слитно:

- если они не употребляются без "не"

- если они не употребляются без "не" в качестве антонимов к отдельным словосочетаниям

- если качественные прилагательные не образуют антонимы с приставкой "не"

- при наличии слов очень, весьма, крайне, в высшей степени, совершенно, вполне, 
почти, отчасти, совсем, чрезвычайно

- если прилагательные называют признак и их можно заменить cинонимами без "не"

Comment: Не с прилагательными пишется слитно:

- если от прилагательных нельзя образовать антонимы с "не"

- со сравнительной степенью прилагательных

- если прилагательные отрицают наличие признака

Дальше просто идёт список "всегда слитного"

Comment: Конечно, слитно. Если уж ОЧЕНЬ хочется написать раздельно, надо писать "это не будет удобочитаемым".